# It takes minutes to access the network after conneted the hotspot created by Ubuntu

Tags: networking, 16.04, windows-10, hot-spot

The host machine is **Ubuntu 16.04**. It connects to the internet using **wired way** and creates a hotspot using the WIFI module. When another computer with **windows 10** systerm connects this WIFI. It will take serval minutes for the Win10 to connect to the internet.
Every time I have to wait minutes long, its sad! Please help, thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your OS.  You tagged an EOL/ESM release (14.04) but then contradict that by mentioning Ubuntu 16.04.  Please clarify.

Comment: My OS is Ubuntu 16.04, but the tag only have 14.04

Comment: Please edit your question and correct the tag, there is a 16.04

Comment: The question is very hw specific. Please indicate brands and devices in use.